# Python 2-D array assignment

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

My question is as follows: 
I have some lists such as [1], [1,2], [1,3,1], and I want to put them in a 2D array result, which is [[1],[1,2],[1,3,1]]. Are there any simple ways to do that? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried putting two square brackets around it? e.g. [1], [1,2], [1,3,1] -> [  [1], [1,2], [1,3,1]  ]

Comment: In python, these are lists. And an item in a list can be of any type. More info on them in the python documentation here : https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Answer (score 1):

yea, there are

```
l1, l2, l3=[1], [1,2], [1,3,1]

biglist=[l1,l2,l3]
```

Comment: The OP said "2D array". You should put `np.array()` around your result

Comment: @Bazingaa considering the question, OP likely does not know that what other languages call "arrays" are called "lists" in python. I doubt he's looking for numpy arrays

Comment: Also the example of his desired output is just a list of lists, if OP comes back to clarify I'll adjust accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l1 = [1]
l2 = [1, 2]
l3 = [1, 3, 1]
result = []
result.append(l1)
result.append(l2)
result.append(l3)
print(result)
```

Or you can write shorter:

```
l1 = [1]
l2 = [1, 2]
l3 = [1, 3, 1]
result = [l1,l2,l3]
print(result)
```

output:

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 3, 1]]
```

Comment: The OP said "2D array". You should put np.array() around your result

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think there is something exactly the same as a 2D Array, you can just put those lists in a 2D list (as SuperStew shows):

```
a = [1]
b = [1,2]
c = [1,3,1]
d = [a,b,c]
```

Now, you can call `d` like you would a 2D Array. For Example:

```
print d[0][0]
print d[2][1]
```

Returns:

```
1
3
```

Answer (score -1):

There you go:

x, y, z = [1], [1,2], [1,3,1]

[x,y,z]